# How to make user input average calculation on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add some simple calculation to my javascript code. When the user inputs a number, next, we will be knowing the average of all the number they input. But's my code still not works.

```JS
var n = parseInt(prompt("Silahkan masukan responden untuk menilai MOS"), 10);
var i = 1;
var nt = n + 1;

do {
    var total = parseInt(prompt("Penilaian Responden " + i + " :"), 10);
    i++;
}
while (i < nt);

var rata = parseInt(total / nt);
alert('Maka nilai MOS rata-ratanya nilai ' + rata);
```

Comment: `var total = parseInt(prompt("Penilaian Responden " + i + " :"), 10);` is not totaling anything. It just keeps replacing the variable with the current user's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var n = parseInt(prompt("Silahkan masukan responden untuk menilai MOS"), 10);
    var i = 1;
    var nt = n + 1;
    var total = 0;
    do {
      total = total + parseInt(prompt("Penilaian Responden " + i + " :"), 10);
      i++;
    }

    while (i < nt);

    var rata = parseInt(total / n);
    alert('Maka nilai MOS rata-ratanya nilai ' + rata);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting `total` (as well as redeclare it) in every iteration, you need to declare it first and then just add to it:

```
var total = 0;
do {
  total += parseInt(prompt("Penilaian Responden " + i + " :"), 10);
  i++;
}
```

This will fix your issue, then there are many improvements you can do to your code as well FYI. For instance, a `for` loop is much more appropriate than a `do`-`while` in this case.

Comment: Thanks and how about the user input average calcution,

Comment: @ljosalfar What about it? It works now that `total` is added to properly, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming its a logical error in the calculation of total.Anyway 
it should

**code**

```
var total=0,temp;
do{
   temp=parseInt(prompt("Penilaian Responden "+ i + " :"),10);
   total=total+temp;
}while(i<nt);
```

You don't seem to be adding total with the previous value of total in the iteration

Comment: Logical errors are errors that cause the program to function incorrectly(not getting the desired output).It doesn't cause the program to crash.In your case,your calculation of total was wrong.You should calculate the sum of all totals obtained in every iteration

Comment: I just want to add some formula example like this

**bold
total = (5*2 )+ (4*1)+(3*2)+(2*3)+(1*2) / 10

**


10 is the number what i input for the first.